# GDB unused variable

Tags: c, variables, gcc, gdb, trace

Is it possible to get the value of unused variable using GDB? Is there some configuration for GCC so that the garbage value of the unused variable will be shown not 'optimized out'?

c file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    printf("value of x: %d",x);

}
```

In the gdb I want to get the garbage value of variable y.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/charmae/workspace/AVT/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at file4.c:7
7       printf("value of x: %d",x);
(gdb) info locals
x = 2789364
(gdb) p y
$1 = <optimized out>
(gdb) p x
$2 = 2789364
```

Comment: i have tried compiling with "gcc -O0 -g file.c" but it doesnt work.

Comment: Instead of saying "it doesn't work," how about telling us what happened?

Comment: @JohnZwinck got same output as mentioned above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with GDB. The entity that optimized that variable out is the compiler (probably GCC in your case). You might force it to keep it by declaring the variable as volatile

A better question is - why are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm making a program visualization and i need values for the declared variables....i was just wondering if unused declared variable is allocated to the memory, if so then the variable should have a value..

Comment: If the compiler has optimized the variable out then no - they are not allocated storage space in memory so there is no value.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with gcc. Either the compiler has compiled code to maintain the value, or it hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

You might add an `y=y;` statement. That would force `y` to be used, and with `gcc -O0 -g`  keep track of it (at least on my Linux/Debian/Sid/AMD64 with  `gcc 4.6.2` and `gdb 7.3.50`)